# CommandLink missing in controlsfx' new version controlsfx-8.20.7

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I developed my JavaFX app with ControlsFX version controlsfx-8.0.6_20. When I upgrade the ControlsFX to its newest version, controlsfx-8.20.7, my sources become uncompilable, discovering some of the classes previously found in ControlFx' previous version are not found, including the CommandLink. Is there a remedy for this?

Answer (score 1):

ControlsFX dialogs will be integrated in JavaFX 8u40 but with heavily changed API. Old dialogs API is deprecated as of 8.20.7 but it is not yet removed. New dialogs API which will be part of the JavaFX 8u40 is currently in openjfx-dialogs.jar and can be downloaded from its own [repository](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs) or will be downloaded automatically as dependency from maven repository. This is partially cause of the incompatibilities in the newest ControlsFX version.

More information about this can be found at ControlsFX forum in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/controlsfx-dev/APokeoMFnHE) post.

Unfortunately, in addition, some classes changed API (like Action) and if you are using them, your code must be ported to new API when upgrading from 8.0.6_20 to 8.20.7 version. CommandLink class specifically, as I can see, changed name to [CommandLinksDialog](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/CommandLinksDialog.html).